# Python: Remove items from a list and keep the original list order

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, set

I have a list of animals:

```
list_animals = ['dog', 'cat', 'cow', 'tiger', 'lion', 'snake', 'lion']
```

and a set of pets:

```
set_pets = set(['dog', 'cat'])
```

I want to remove pets in `set_pets` from `list_animals` but still keep the original orders of list_animals. Would this be possible?

I tried to do:
`set(list_animals) - set_pets`, but then it doesn't keep the original animal orders ...

Thanks!

Comment: Definitely a dupe - just use a list comp: `[x for x in list_animals if x not in set_pets]`

Comment: FYI, sets are not ordered in Python.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this easily with a list comprehension:

```
result = [a for a in list_animals if a not in set_pets]
['cow', 'tiger', 'lion', 'snake', 'lion']
```

I had a second method in here that uses `list.remove()`, but it was inefficient. List comp is the way to go.

Comment: This is very inefficient compared to list comp.

Comment: Honestly, I wouldn't even keep the for loop in this answer- `list.remove()` is going to search through (potentially) all the items in `list_animals` every time you call it.

Comment: Good point, although he did specifically say he wants to *remove* all of the pets, so I guess I had `list.remove()` in my brain :P

Answer (score 1):

```
list_animals = ['dog', 'cat', 'cow', 'tiger', 'lion', 'snake', 'lion']
set_pets = set(['dog', 'cat'])
list_animals = list(filter(lambda x: x not in set_pets, list_animals))
print(list_animals)
```

Outputs

```
['cow', 'tiger', 'lion', 'snake', 'lion']
```